# Check if row exists before inserting

Tags: functions, database, wpdb

Not sure what I am doing wrong here but I am looking to add a row into db but only if row doesnt already exit with that email address
Please see my code below:

```
 function register_user() {
global $wpdb; 
$tablename = $wpdb->prefix."tablename";
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];  


$checkIfExists = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tablename WHERE email = $email");
$checkRows = mysqli_num_rows($checkIfExists);

if ($checkRows > 0) {
    header('Location: ../register.php?');
}
else{
$options = [
  'cost' => 11,
];
$passwordFromPost = $_POST['password'];
$hash = password_hash($passwordFromPost, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options);
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "tablename"; 
$wpdb->insert($table_name, array(
  'name' => $name, 
  'email' => $email,
  'password' => $hash
),array(
  '%s',
  '%s',
  '%s') 
);
}
```

However it seems to be just my passing the if and going straight to else even though email in database is there.

Answer (score 5):

There are several problems with your function. For example, `$tablename` points to a table that does not exist. And you don't need it anyway.
If you are trying to create a new user if that email does not exist then try this:

```
function register_user() {
    global $wpdb; 
    
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];  

    $checkIfExists = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->users WHERE email = '$email'");

    if ($checkIfExists == NULL) {

        $userdata = array(
            'user_login'    =>  $name,
            'user_email'    =>  $email,
            'user_pass'     =>  $password,
        );

        $user = wp_insert_user( $userdata );
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: this is a custom table i have created.. its not wpuser table

Comment: this also doesnt work row still being added

Comment: We don't know what the structure is for your custom table.  Is the name of the table really `tablename`?  Read the wpdb codex page and get a simple query working before you try to solve the insert issue.  https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb